# Where to copy a 3rd party assembly in your Visual Studio project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, .net-assembly

My operating system is Widows 7. I am using Visual Studio 2015.

I have a solution `Sln1` which has 2 projects `Proj1` and `Proj2` both projects are of Class Library type.

In Windows Explorer I can see:

- I have a folder **c:\MyWork\Sln1** which has the solution file named 
  **`Sln1.sln`** and it also has 2 folders named **Proj1** and **Proj2**.
- I have a folder **c:\MyWork\Sln1\Proj1** which has the project file named
  **`Proj1.csproj`** and it also has 3 folders named **bin**, **obj** and **Properties**.
- I have a folder **c:\MyWork\Sln1\Proj2** which has the project file named
  **`Proj2.csproj`** and it also has 3 folders named **bin**, **obj** and **Properties**.

I have a 3rd party assembly (**`Telerik.Web.UI.dll`**) which is in folder **C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for ASP.NET AJAX Q3 2015\Bin45**.

I want to use this 3rd party assembly in the source code of `Proj2` only. But I dont want the project `Proj2` to access it from its current location. Instead I want the project `Proj2` to have its own copy of this 3rd party assembly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the dll file to the desired location for example (`solution/project/lib`). Then in vs2015 open the solution explorer `Ctrl + Alt + L`.

Then under the project, you want to add the lib to right-click on reference.
[image]

Then click on add reference. Go to the browse tab and in the right bottom side click on browse. 
[image]

Here you can select the dll you want to reference in the project. The 3th party library is now ready to use in your project.

Comment: what is the desired location in my solution/project? that is my question.

Comment: It does not really matter to the functionality. I like to place all my libraries in a folder called lib. But you can call it whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the 3rd party library in the "Proj2" project location, just copy the DLL file (i.e. Telerik.Web.UI.dll) to a folder in that section (for example under lib, etc.) then in your project(s) go to your Solution Explorer, under the References right click and choose "Add Reference...", then click on Browse and choose your DLL accordingly from the location that you copied earlier.

I hope this will be a useful tip for you.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to take into account is **version control**. No matter where you put it, make sure that the library is under version control, or at least that sufficient information to retrieve it. Also, check that you reference it in your project using relative paths, so anyone can build using only files within his own working copy.

I generally use a structure like this:

```
\
   \libraries
      \lib1
      \lib2
   \source
      \proy1
      \proy2
```

So that it's easy to checkout the whole thing, incluiding all dependencies and use those for building everything.